# Integrating zbar scanner into android app

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code

In my onCreate method Im creating an webView and then loading an HTML file thats saved in my assets folder. This is all working fine. When a button is pressed it sends a call using javascript to this method to open the qr code scanner.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()        
    {  
        /* On Android 1.1 shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will be called every time the user clicks a link, 
         * but on Android 1.5 it will be called for every page load, even if it was caused by calling loadUrl()! */  
        @Override  
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
        {               
            System.out.println(url);                

            if (url.equals("fake://qr_scan")) 
            {
                launchQRScanner(view);
            }
            return false;  
        }  
    });
```

Here is the method launchQRScanner()

```
  public void launchQRScanner(View v) {
    if (isCameraAvailable()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});
        startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Rear Facing Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

So this works for the first time the button is pressed. The qr code reader open as an intent, it scans, disappears and returns the value correctly. But for every time after the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading() doesn't get called when the button is pressed. Possibly has something to do with leaving the app and coming back? Can't seem to figure it out.

BTW this is the project that I used to implement the qr code reader 
https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, Just had to reload the webView after the barcode is scanned. Simple fix.